# fetching large data and then counting from them

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know if I fetch large amount of data from all different tables of MySQL then how can I count the total no of values of a particular row?

```
$thedata= mysql_query("select comment,Date,hits,abc,xyz from fk_views where onid='$thepicid'");
```

I want to count the total hits fetched by this query.
Normally we do like

```
mysql_num_rows($thedata);
```

This query will tell the total no of data fetched not the total no of hits fetched.

Comment: what do you meant by hits? Also `mysql` extension is deprecated. Migrate to the `mysqli` extension.

Comment: Are you asking how to get `SUM(hits)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Barmar suggested, you probably want to use `SUM` but, isn't the field `hits` itself returning exactly what you want to get? How is that column incrementing and how?

Comment: for getting it ihave to right a diffrent code like
    $thedata= mysql_query("select hits from fk_views where onid='$thepicid'");
    mysql_num_rows($thedata);

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? Because `SELECT SUM(hits) FROM fk_views WHERE noid=$thepicid` I think would solve your problem, have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$thedata= mysqli_query("select SUM(hits) as hitcount,comment,Date,hits,abc,xyz from fk_views where onid='$thepicid'");
```

This will get you the sum(hits) also in the same query.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$thedata= mysqli_query($con, "select comment,Date,hits,abc,xyz from fk_views where onid='$thepicid'");

$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($thedata);
echo $row_count;
?>
```

Comment: Other than using a different MySQL API, how is this any different from what he wrote?

Comment: But won't this get the same answer as his original code? How does it solve his problem?

Comment: Yeah.. you are correct.. maybe he is trying to get sum of hits